# pinv result diff - matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

As part of our homework we need to map imageA into iamge B 

I'm using this code for inverse mapping

`A = zeros(8,8);

A = [imageB(1,1) imageB(2,1) 0 0 1 0 (-1)*(imageB(1,1))imageA(1,1) (-1)(imageB(2,1))imageA(1,1); 

    0 0 imageB(1,1) imageB(2,1) 0 1 (-1)(imageB(1,1))imageA(2,1) (-1)(imageB(2,1))imageA(2,1);

    imageB(1,2) imageB(2,2) 0 0 1 0 (-1)(imageB(1,2))imageA(1,2) (-1)(imageB(2,2))imageA(1,2);

    0 0 imageB(1,2) imageB(2,2) 0 1 (-1)(imageB(1,2))imageA(2,2) (-1)(imageB(2,2))imageA(2,2);

    imageB(1,3) imageB(2,3) 0 0 1 0 (-1)(imageB(1,3))imageA(1,3) (-1)(imageB(2,3))imageA(1,3);

    0 0 imageB(1,3) imageB(2,3) 0 1 (-1)(imageB(1,3))imageA(2,3) (-1)(imageB(2,3))imageA(2,3);

    imageB(1,4) imageB(2,4) 0 0 1 0 (-1)(imageB(1,4))imageA(1,4) (-1)(imageB(2,4))imageA(1,4);

    0 0 imageB(1,4) imageB(2,4) 0 1 (-1)(imageB(1,4))imageA(2,4) (-1)(imageB(2,4))*imageA(2,4)];

imageA(1,4); imageA(2,4)];

B  = reshape(imageA,[],1);`

 `D = pinv(A)*B;`

my friend however uses this code :
 `D = inv(A'*A)*A'*B;`

i get the same values as he does except i get 0.0000 and he get -0.0000
all the rest of the numbers positive or negative are the same.

why is this ? and what is the correct answer?
what do you suggest i can do in order to check my results easly?

Comment: Your friend is using a POOR version compared to the pinv result.

Comment: @woodchips isn't it basically the same formula ?

Comment: NO! pinv does not use that expression, which although MATHEMATICALLY the same, is not NUMERICALLY the same. There are very good reasons why pinv does not simply use that expression, because of the interaction with in floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like these differences stem from numerical instabilities. How big are they with respect to machine precision (`eps`)? 
Why don't you use `backslash`?

```
>> D = A \ B;
```

Comment: nice to see fellow Israeli. 3.77490637859040
-0.0851252221459957
-0.154767551596968
2.27267913596643
-180.056724602071
-98.3195068541737
-0.000604560748425658
-0.00122497904957724 these are the numbers i'm getting backslash worked like a charm, thanks